# Masculine country or feminine country

Tags: genre, noms-propres, toponymes

How do you know if a country is feminine or masculine? If you say "in a (feminine) country", you would use en, but how would you know if the country is feminine or not? Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: You have this article : http://www.slate.fr/story/11269/pourquoi-certains-noms-de-pays-sont-ils-masculins-et-dautres-feminins

Comment: Like any other French noun, by looking the determiner and the adjectives used with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Pays_masculin_feminin.png) may be helpful for remembering the genders of countries. [Here's another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ca2y.jpg) which includes information on the use of articles.

Comment: Two points: 1. Your answer is at risk of link-rot. If the links die, your answer won't work anymore. 2. The maps don't include country names, so you have to know geography as well to make use of them.

Comment: Third point: this map is false, at least for "le Liechtenstein", "le Royaume-Uni", probably also Madagascar

Answer (score -2):

Très succinctement (il y en a 200, il faudrait les parcourir tous):

http://fr.mapsofworld.com/world-maps/grande-carte.html

*nb: cette carte a des étrangetés (la Guyane française est anglaise !)*

**De manière générale, en regardant la fin: e féminin, autre voyelle ou consonne: masculin.**

- les pays en Europe de l'Ouest sont féminins, sauf le Portugal, le Danemark, le Luxembourg, le Royaume-Uni, le Liechstenstein, le Vatican, Le Monténégro, Monaco , San-Marin, Andorre, Chypre, Malte (sans article), ainsi que le Kosovo.
- les pays d'Afrique/moyen orient sont masculins, sauf les pays finissant en ie / ye;
- les pays d'Amérique du Sud sont masculins, sauf ceux finissant en e (Argentine, Colombie, Bolivie, Guyane);

**- pour les autres: fin en e => féminin;**

- quelques pays sans déterminant à examiner au cas par cas.
- et quelques pays au pluriel.

**Exceptions: sont masculins: Mexique, Bélize, Zimbabwe (prononcer oué), Suriname (anciennement Surinam).**

Comment: + Le Royaume-Uni.

Comment: @HorsSujet - effectivement. Je pensais l'Angleterre.

Comment: Le Monténégro, le Kosovo, le Kazakhstan, Les Pays-Bays, Le Liechtenstein, Le Vatican ainsi que Monaco sont des pays d'Europe dont le nom est masculin.

Comment: Les Pays-Bas = la Hollande- j'indique à la fin qu'il y a quelques pays au pluriel (pas très nombreux). Monaco n'a pas de déterminant. J'ai effectivement oublié l'Etat du Vatican (je n'ai jamais entendu l'appeler un pays. Géographiquement, c'est minuscule). le Kazahstan est en Asie. J'ai effectivement oublié le Liechtenstein, et les pays d'ex-yougoslavie. Réponse changée.

Comment: La Hollande n'est qu'une région des Pays-Bas parmi d'autres; confondre les deux est une erreur fréquente, comme l'est la confusion entre Royaume-Uni et Angleterre. Monaco n'a pas de déterminant mais est répertorié comme masculin. Le Vatican est un état souverain depuis 1929, le plus petit du monde certes, mais il s'agit bien d'un pays. Une petite partie du Kazakhstan se trouve à l'ouest du fleuve Oural, elle est donc située en Europe.

Comment: @jlliagre . Merci pour ces précisions. L'Oural est une chaîne de montagnes.

Comment: Pas seulement. L'extrémité sud de la chaîne de montagne appelée Oural se trouve en Russie. Un fleuve de même nom y prends sa source et délimite l'Europe de l'Asie, en particulier au Kazakhstan.